# How to override jquery method?

Tags: jquery

> I want to override the jquery method for example `animate()` with some more functionality. So how can I override the jquery built-in methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sub method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.sub/) to override the built-in methods. Is that you are looking for?

Here's an example:

**Override some jQuery methods to provide new functionality.**

```
(function() {
var myjQuery = jQuery.sub();
myjQuery.fn.remove = function() {
// New functionality: Trigger a remove event
this.trigger( "remove" );
// Be sure to call the original jQuery remove method
return jQuery.fn.remove.apply( this, arguments );
};
myjQuery(function( $ ) {
$( ".menu" ).click(function() {
$( this ).find( ".submenu" ).remove();
});
// A new remove event is now triggered from this copy of jQuery
$( document ).on( "remove", function( event ) {
$( event.target ).parent().hide();
});
});
})();
// Regular jQuery doesn't trigger a remove event when removing an element
// This functionality is only contained within the modified 'myjQuery'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-Ask-Ben-Overriding-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm

This has some pretty good explanation.